# zen coding not working in Visual Studio

Tags: html, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, web-essentials, emmet

I have Web Essentials 2015.2 installed.

When I, for instance, type "div" and then hit tab, it just selects the following block of html rather than adding a div tag. No zen coding features are working.

I'm using VS 2015 Pro Update 3 RC (version 14.0.25402.00) and the .NET Core Tools (Preview 1) and wonder if some of this is just not compatible?

I also have ReSharper installed, which I understand frequently interferes with shortcuts. Could that be it?

I have no clue what other info to include. Questions welcome if my problem solution are not obvious...

Answer (score 13):

Problem is web essentials plugin.

Solution: Go to Visual Studio Marketplace.  Type in Zencoding all one word and install the first plug in.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.ZenCoding

Or install it on Visual Studio (works perfectly with 2017) - Tools -Extensions & Updates - Online - zencoding.  Close VS and restart.

It must be some bug with resharper because I couldnt get zen coding to work on web essentials plugin.

Comment: I installed only zencoding  without web essentials and it works for me on vs 2017

Answer (score 5):

I have cleared `resharper` cache (global and solution) and disabled any
unused extensions and after restarting VS everything works.

UPDATE :
 Changed TAB action in the editor,
 `Resharper > Options > Editor > Editor behavior` and UNCHECK `Use tab for navigation in code`.

Comment: There are so many hidden twerks like this in Resharper, extremely annoying. Finding an answer like this also took me about 20 minutes, because I thought zen coding was somehow disabled in Web Essentials.

Comment: I only see the option Use tab/Shift+tab keys for structural navigation but unticking it makes no difference to Zen coding (Visual Studio 2017). So annoying, Zen coding still not working

Answer (score 3):

Web essentials 2017 has Zen Coding in it. If you had Zen Coding installed before loading Web essentials it breaks.

1. Uninstall both.
2. install Web essentials.
3. install Zen coding

It now works as intended.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue in Visual Studio 2017, but after updating it, then
uninstalling the ZenCoding extension and reinstalling the ZenCoding extension, worked for me, even together with Resharper

Answer (score 1):

For me the Zen coding was disabled(make sure you install it first), go to Tools and click Extensions and Updates and then Enable Zen coding. It's working now.

Answer (score 1):

I had to install the `Zenconding` extension manually. Seems like it's not part of web essentials anymore...